# Copying from closed workbook

Tags: vba, excel

I have been searching for over a hour now and can not find anything that works for this and would appreciate any help at all. I have been using the following code:

```
Sub copySheet()
Dim srcBook As Workbook
Set srcBook = Application.Workbooks.Open(ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Book1.xlsx")
srcBook.Sheets("Sheet1").Copy After:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
srcBook.Close False
End Sub
```

This copies as expected however, in the copied workbook it creates a new sheet "Sheet1(2)" instead of adding this to the existing sheet1. If repeated it creates "Sheet1(3)", "Sheet1(4)", "Sheet1(5)", etc...

I am really stuck with this and cannot find an answer anywhere.

Comment: "in the copied workbook it creates a new sheet "Sheet1(2)" instead of adding this to the existing sheet1" - that's how copying a sheet works: if the copied sheet has the same name as an existing sheet then the copied sheet gets a numeric suffix to make its name unique.  What exactly is the behavior you expect?

Comment: You're **copying after** "Sheet1", just exactly as your code is telling it to do (it's what `srcBook.Sheets("Sheet1").Copy After` does specifically - it copies the indicated sheet to the other workbook *after* the sheet you tell it). Are you trying to add data to the existing Sheet1 instead?

Comment: Did you want to overwrite Sheet1 in the current workbook?

Comment: Yes, I am trying to add it to the existing sheet 1 if this is possible. Thanks.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because OP is posting nearly identical questions an hour apart: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23897000/excel-vba-copying-object-from-closed-workbook

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two possible tasks at issue here:

1. Copying a sheet, which your code does successfully
2. Copying the *contents* of a sheet, which is also called a *Range*

It sounds like what you actually want to do is copy a Range to an existing worksheet. Try this instead:

```
Sub copySheetContents()
    Dim srcBook As Workbook
    Set srcBook = Application.Workbooks.Open(ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Book1.xlsx")

    srcBook.Sheets("Sheet1").UsedRange.Copy

    ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(1, 1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, _
        Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False

    srcBook.Close False
End Sub
```

Note that the above assumes that your used range in the source workbook starts at cell A1.

Comment: Thanks for this, I am trying to copy an object from the closed workbook, your code seems to only copy the data. I modified the UsedRange to Range("A1:F30") which covered the object however, this still did not copy the object and instead just copied the data. Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: By "object", do you mean something like a picture or a chart "on top of" the spreadsheet? Might want to try `Paste:=xlPasteAll` instead. Here are the options for what you can paste: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff837425(v=office.15).aspx

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to just overwrite what is in your current sheet1:

```
Sub copySheet()
Dim srcBook As Workbook
Set srcBook = Application.Workbooks.Open(ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Book1.xlsx")
srcBook.Sheets("Sheet1").UsedRange.Copy Destination:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(1,1)
srcBook.Close False
End Sub
```